# JQuery find child element inner text and replace with IMG HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a little help with a Javascript function I am creating. In essence, I need to loop through a set of DIVs with class .DetailRow and find a child DIV's content (inner text). If this text is matched to a variable, then I need to replace this inner text with an IMG HTML statement.

BTW I am kinda new at this (4 months old!) so apologies if the issue is simple, but I have tried a few combos and I am stuck.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="DetailRow" style="display: ">..</div>
<div class="DetailRow" style="display: ">..</div>
<div class="DetailRow" style="display: ">
   <div class="Label">Availability:</div>
   <div class="Value">in stock + Free Shipping</div>
</div>
```

Example, if I find "in stock" in the LABEL inner text, I want to replace it with the value of the variable "instock" which is an IMG HTML statement. See my code attempt below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
    var instock = '<img src="https://linktoimgfolder/instock.gif" title="Product available, usually ships 24hrs to 48hrs after order receipt" style="margin-top:-3px;">';  
    var lowstock = '<img src="https://linktoimgfolder/lowstock.gif" title="Product stcok low, order today so you do not miss out">';
    var nostock = '<img src="https://linktoimgfolder/outstock.gif" title="Product out of stock, could ship 1 to 2 weeks after order receipt">';

    $('div.DetailRow')each(function(){
        if (indexOf($(this).childNodes[1].innerHTML, "in stock") > 0) {
             $(this).childNodes[2].innerHTML = "";
             $(this).childNodes[2].innerHTML = instock;
        } else if (indexOf($(this).childNodes[1].innerHTML, "low stock") > 0) {
             $(this).childNodes[2].innerHTML = "";
             $(this).childNodes[2].innerHTML = lowstock;
        } else {
             $(this).childNodes[2].innerHTML = "";
             $(this).childNodes[2].innerHTML = nostock;
        };
    });
});
</script>​
```

By the way,m I cannot match text exactly as the text beyond the "+" will change from time to time, thus I am trying indexOf.

Many thanks in advance for your assistance!

M

Comment: Is the `style:"display: "` intentional?

Comment: What does it do now when you run it?  Also, you are missing the period before each after the selector.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. the "display:" is not intentional, it is CMS generated, so not my doing.

Comment: Hi Seano666 I get a syntax error so yours may be the answer. I am afraid I do not see where the missing period goes though, can you be more specific pls. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [**:contains**](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector

```
var stock = {'in stock': instock, 'low stock': lowstock, 'no stock': nostock};

Object.keys(stock).forEach(function(key) {
    $('div.DetailRow div:contains(' + key + ')').html(stock[key]);
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/btYjs/)

A pure jQuery solution:

```
$.each(stock, function(key, value) {
    $('div.DetailRow div:contains(' + key + ')').html(value);
});
```

Comment: @user2469528, consider using the pure jQuery solution. `Object.keys` and `Array.prototype.forEach` are recent additions to ECMA; not all browsers support it.

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in this line `$('div.DetailRow')each(function(){` and then you can use jQuery `.text()` and `.html()` to check value and update.

Try:

```
$('div.DetailRow').find("div").each(function(){
        if($(this).text().indexOf("in stock")!=-1){
            $(this).text("");
            $(this).html(instock);
        }else if($(this).text().indexOf("low stock")!=-1){
            $(this).text("");
            $(this).html(lowstock);
        }else{
            $(this).text("");
            $(this).html(nostock);
        }
    });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gjd8t/1/)**</kbd>

**NOTE:** Updated code to find `div` inside `div.DetailsRow`. Change it according to your requirement.

Comment: Actually there's no need to use `.text("")` at all. The `html` is enough. http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/gjd8t/2/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but what is need to achieve is a little different than your code does, and now seeing your reply, it prompted me!.